# Public repository allows others to edit my code?

Tags: git, bitbucket

If I have a public repository on bitbucket does that mean other uses can view **and** edit my code, or can they simply view it?

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Repository+privacy%2C+permissions%2C+and+more

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In public repos, all users (and usually non-users as well) can view and download your code.  They can only edit if given explicit permissions to do so.